# Overriding broken equals

Tags: java, equals

I have some third party code that has a lot of classes with broken equals() and hash-code implementations. I cannot change the third-party code but need the equals method badly. To overcome this I came up with the the following approaches:

1) Create an EqualsUtility which has a bunch of overloaded static equals() methods.

**Problem**: the class will become very large as the third-party code grows.

2) Create adapter classes for all the third party classes and write an equals  method.

**Problem**: Too many new classes are created.

Is there a third, more clean way to do this.

Comment: I don't know how this helps but I am currently using choice-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to check the object equality with some 3rd party lib, for example with the ApacheCommoms [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html). But that could be not a very good solution, since it uses reflection for comparison. Furthermore, it doesn't help with hash code implementation.

IMO, extending base classes and overriding equals and hashcode methods are prefferable. Any other solution, including aspects, 3rd party libs for deep object comparison, some proxy objects, are not good for performance and in some cases for understanding of your code.

Comment: Indeed, this way you can use the objects in collections etc that rely on equals/hashcode working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Check out AspectJ.   It's an Aspect Oriented programming library for Java that let's you do exactly what you want to do.  You describe an entity called a pointcut that corresponds roughly to in this case a method invocation of the equals() method on the library's objects.

You then write code that gets executed when that pointcut is hit.  You can write different types of pointcuts.  So for instance you can have your code execute before the equals() method, after the equals() method, or around the equals() method.  If you write an around() type you can choose to handle the call your self or do some work then call the original method.

You could do an around() and rewrite the equals method so it is correct for your situation.

Very powerful stuff.